# Upgrading Rails Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am upgrading the rails environment and try to update fields
 but page.replace_html is not working correctly i am using in update method like

```
  render :update do |page|
    page.replace_html category_type + '_categories', :partial => 'categories',:locals => {:type => category_type, :categories => categories}
  end
```

But i am getting error like -

```
Element.update("risk_fields_categories", "\u003Cdiv style='margin-top: 
20px;' id='risk_fields_categories'\u003E\n  \n
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: It does not look like an error. According to documentation it is supposed to create an `Element.update` like that...

Comment: @sadaf2605   how to resolve it ?

Comment: The `Element.update` that you provided is not an error message. According to http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/JavaScriptGenerator/GeneratorMethods/replace_html it is supposed to create `Element.update` like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved This issue myself -

I have create first update.js.haml and write the code like -

```
jQuery('#test').html('#{ j render :partial => 'edit', :locals => {:type => @type, :cate => @cat}}');
```

And add another file assests/javascript/ujs folder with name test.js.coffee.